# Display column name containing current date.

Tags: sql-server

I tried the following script but it does not work.

```
DECLARE @STOCKDATE varchar(32)
SET @STOCKDATE = 'STOCK BALANCE AS OF ' + CAST(getdate() as varchar(32))

SELECT SUM(qty) as @STOCKDATE FROM.....
```

How should I do it?

Comment: You can't create a column name on-the-fly. You could use dynamic SQL (sp_ExecuteSQL) to execute SQL that you've assembled from pieces/parts. It should be noted that the column name isn't something that an end-user should be concerned about. Your application, not the database, should handle formatting and display of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL as otherwise you cannot specify an alias from a variable:

```
DECLARE @STOCKDATE varchar(32)
SET @STOCKDATE = 'STOCK BALANCE AS OF ' + CAST(getdate() as varchar(32))

DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT SUM(qty) as [' + @STOCKDATE + '] FROM.....'
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: It seems to work. But how do I escape the single quote in the @SQL string?? I have something like this in my sql script example

Comment: Ok, change quotes to brackets `[]`, it will work for anything (apart from brackets inside but they are less likely...) Or replace `'` with `''` in your variable `@STOCKDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Szymon is correct but only a minor modification

```
DECLARE @STOCKDATE varchar(32)
SET @STOCKDATE = 'STOCK BALANCE AS OF ' + CAST(getdate() as varchar(32))

DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT SUM(qty) as ''' + @STOCKDATE + ''' FROM.....'
EXEC (@sql)
```

Adding 2 single quotes before and after the `@STOCKDATE` so the variable would be passed without any exception